# rails model did not work with distinct statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, distinct

Here is my problem: I was querying data from `sqlite3` based on `rails 5.1.6`, I wanted to select raws which have the same event name called `login` at the same day, and which distinct from users(user may log in system several times at the same day). Below is my code:

```
class Query < ApplicationRecord

  def self.event_finder(name, time, **options)

    opt = {
      country_code: "CA",
    }

    if options.any?
      opt = opt.merge(options)
    end

    self.where("event_time >= ?", time)
        .where("event_time < ?", time + 1.day)
        .where(opt)
        .distinct(:user_id)
  end

end
```

when I ran my model in `rails console`, it did return, but did not return correct data, the result was duplicate in keyword `user_id`. So how do I remove duplicates using rails model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that as like below

```
self.where("event_time >= ?", time)
    .where("event_time < ?", time + 1.day)
    .where(opt)
    .select('distinct(user_id)')
```

or you can use like this

```
self.where("event_time >= ?", time)
    .where("event_time < ?", time + 1.day)
    .where(opt)
    .distinct.pluck(:user_id)
```

this also works

```
self.where("event_time >= ?", time)
    .where("event_time < ?", time + 1.day)
    .where(opt)
    .pluck("DISTINCT user_id")
```

Comment: the second one is absolutely the best practice in my problem, I used it and correct data is returned!

Comment: @weirdhoney Great to hear it

Comment: @weirdhoney If you helped with that answer please accept this to a correct answer & help StackOverflow user in future reference